# Returning value outside of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, graphql, graphql-js

I'm looking to use graphQL to query a docker machine api and get a list of containers for react docker admin style project. I'm using dockerode an NPM module to make the request. The first function getCOntainerById is how I would typically return some items from rethinkdb.

I can't seem to figure out how to return the containers array in the docker.listContainers function as it's only defined inside the scope and undefined at the end of the fetchContainers function return.

```
import Docker from 'dockerode'
var docker = new Docker({host: 'http://127.0.0.1', port: 52376});

export default {
  getContainerById: {
    type: Container,
    args: {
      id: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)}
    },
    async resolve(source, {id}, {rootValue}) {
      isLoggedIn(rootValue);
      const container = await r.table('containers').get(id);
      if (!container) {
        throw errorObj({_error: 'Container not found'});
      }
      return container;
    }
  },
  fetchContainers: {
    type: new GraphQLList(Container),
    async resolve(source, {id}, {rootValue}) {
      isLoggedIn(rootValue);
      docker.listContainers(function(err, containers) {

      });

      if (!containers) {
        throw errorObj({_error: 'Container not found'});
      }

      return containers
    }
  }
};
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async resolve(source, {id}, {rootValue}) {
  isLoggedIn(rootValue);
  const containers = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    docker.listContainers((err, containers) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(containers);
    });
  })

  if (!containers) {
    throw errorObj({_error: 'Container not found'});
  }

  return containers
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems there's always something to learn with JS.